# How to fix 'AffinityPropagation object is not callable' error in Python

Tags: python

I am going to do a clustering task with AffinityPropagation in sklearn and I keep getting this error:
'AffinityPropagation' object is not callable

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
x = stacked_codes.detach().numpy()
AP =AffinityPropagation(affinity='euclidean', convergence_iter=15, copy=True, damping=0.5, max_iter=1000, preference=None, verbose=False)
AP.fit(x)
```

I expect the output of an array of the same size as my input!

Comment: Show us how you are defining `AffinityPropagation`.  Is it a locally defined class, an import, a function, ??

Comment: @John Gordon I import it: from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

Comment: Do you get the error on the line `AP =AffinityPropagation(...)`, or the line `AP.fit(x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by signature, you are using [AffinityPropagation from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html)

you can't expect that the output to be an array, from docs example:

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
>>> clustering = AffinityPropagation().fit(X)
>>> clustering 
AffinityPropagation(affinity='euclidean', convergence_iter=15, copy=True,
          damping=0.5, max_iter=200, preference=None, verbose=False)
>>> clustering.labels_
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
>>> clustering.predict([[0, 0], [4, 4]])
array([0, 1])
>>> clustering.cluster_centers_
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 2]])
```

Comment: The error is `AffinityPropogation object is not callable`, so it seems like something is fundamentally wrong.  This code example certainly does call it.